# Set the length of border (jbutton) in Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have the button in Java (which includes text and icon), but with the default border, the border (the retangle outside the text and icon) is rather long, so how could I set the customed border (width, length) of jbutton. So far, i tried

```
button.setSize(x, y);
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: try `setPreferredSize`... ButtName.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(buttonWidth, buttonHeight));

Comment: look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html, maybe youll find a solution here, but i think the border is everytime such tall as the button itself or the box where the button is in

Comment: The problem is most likely the layout in which the component is embedded.  For more help on that, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

I might get the problem wrong, but you can set the border of a JButton like this:

```
Border border = new LineBorder(Color.WHITE, 12);
JButton button = new JButton("12 Pixel");

button.setBorder(border);
```

You might want to have a look at the [documentation of LineBorder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/LineBorder.html).

Comment: thanks for trying to be helpful :-) But the problem is not the size of the border (the int in your answer controls the _thickness_ of the border), it's the size of the button (aka: layout)

Comment: Okay, I expect you are not searching for button.setBounds(xCoord, yCoord, width, height)?

Answer (score 0):

```
    setLayout(null);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(950, 550));
```

that worked for me just change the Dimensions to your liking...goodluck hope it works! just noticed the date. sorry for gravedigging maybe it'll help someone else though lol